# Android composable re-compose timing when using value/state

Tags: android, composable

I tested for below code, but this will recompose every time when i type in textField(Log show 2 every time I type in textField)

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ComposePracticeTheme {
        HomeSection(modifier = Modifier)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    var input by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val isGreen by remember { derivedStateOf(){input.length>5} }
    Log.d("MainActivity", "1");
    Scaffold {paddingValues ->
        Content(modifier = modifier.padding(paddingValues), input = input, isGreen = isGreen, onChange = {input = it})
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBar(modifier: Modifier, input:String, onChange: (String)->Unit) {
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        TextField(value = input, onValueChange = onChange, modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = 56.dp),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground), contentDescription = "",
                    tint = Color.Unspecified)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Content(modifier: Modifier, input: String, isGreen: Boolean, onChange: (String) -> Unit){
    Log.d("MainActivity", "2");
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        SearchBar(modifier,input, onChange)
        Text(text = if(isGreen)"is Green" else "is Blue", color = if(isGreen) Color.Green else Color.Blue)
    }
}
```

but if I change

```
var input by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val isGreen by remember { derivedStateOf(){input.length>5} }
```

to

```
var input = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val isGreen = remember { derivedStateOf(){input.value.length>5} }
```

it only recompose when isGreen change state, why use value/State cause different behavior?

Comment: val isGreen by remember { derivedStateOf(){input.length>5} }. Here derivedState is of no use as input field change, variable isGreen need to be updated as well ( as there is nothing to buffer), simply use val isGreen = input.length >5